# Android Retrofit2: how to pass request query parameters to response?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm writing a library for a REST API. The library will have to hide to the user the internal complexity of the API as much as possible.

I'm relying on retrofit2 configured to use RxJava to wrap the responses and GSon to parse them.

I'm using [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for a REST service.

```
@GET("search")
Observable<SearchResult> search(@Query("q") String query);

@GET("search")
Observable<SearchResult> search(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params);

@GET("search")
Observable<SearchResult> searchNext(@Query("q") String query, @Query("startKey") String startKey);

@GET("search")
Observable<SearchResult> searchNext(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params, @Query("startKey") String startKey);
```

The search REST service return a JSON

```
{
  "count": 2334,
  "nextBatchKey": "SADjdfsahoi023451sadfjlskdfj02134512",
  "results": [ .... ]
}
```

- the total count of result
- a key to be used to retrieve the next batch of the list
- the actual array of results

To obtain the next batch the service has to be called again with the same parameters and the key returned.

For example, suppose doing a search for `q=foo` and `limit=20`: the REST API will return the results matching string *foo* batched in segments for 20 results each. To get the next batch I would need to create another request with the same two parameters, `q=foo` and `limit=20`, adding `startKey=<the next batch key>`.

I want / need to hide from the user of the library these internal mechanism.

Inside my library I initialize retrofit like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(okHttpClient) // added interceptors
    .baseUrl(baseUrl) // my base url
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)) // custom type adapter factory
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

It generate the service for my interface and use `Gson` to parse the response wrapping it with `RxJava` `Observable`.

Then I obtain the service:

```
MyService service = retrofit.create(MyService.class)
```

Note that I do not write the code of this service, as retrofit works it generate the service automatically using my interface (`MyService`) annotations.

From the library user perspective all this is hidden, he will just receive the service and use it like this:

```
// obtain the service
MyService service = MyLibrarySDK.getService(context);
// perform the search operation
Observable<SearchResult> resultObservable =
    service.search(params);
```

I want the developer using my library to be able to get the next batch like this:

```
// then later result == the SearchResult
Observable<SearchResult> nextBatch =
    result.searchNext();
```

The `searchNext()` call takes no parameters. This means the `SearchResult` object I created in the previous call should internally know which parameters to use when using the method  `searchNext(Map parameters, String key)`.

If the user perform the search call with `q=foo` this information is not received in the response. And I need it.

Since retrofit create the service I don't know how I can intercept the method parameters passed with the call to `service.search()`.

The only idea I had to address this is to use an `OkHttp` interceptor, place the query parameters map in a `ThreadLocal`, then use a custom `Gson` `TypeAdapter` to inject those parameters into the `SearchResult` object.

This solution should technically work but I think it's ugly. Furthermore the interceptor would run for any method of the REST API but I need it only for search queries.

Have you got a better / creative / elegant idea?

Comment: Wouldn't you be getting the query parameters from the data model? Are you doing something like this - https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews ?

Comment: @Krishnaraj was my question bad written? cause what you asking makes me think you didn't understand it. I can improve the question if you tell me where it's confused

Comment: @Krishnaraj anyway, assuming with "data model" you mean the json response of the search: it only contains results, total count and a key to get the next batch. Thus if i need to get the next batch i need that key and all the parameters used for the first call. I want to make this transparent in the client API thus i need a way of passing those parameters around.

Comment: @Krishnaraj you think I should edit my question to make it more clear?

Comment: Ya, think it would better if you add some more details.

Comment: @Krishnaraj tried to improve it, hope I succeed thank you

Comment: Isn't good enough to chain requests and observable?

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli I think I don't get what you mean

Comment: My advice would be to just create the OkHttp calls manually instead of using Retrofit, if you need to have this level of customization and control over what you return. However, if you're bent on using Retrofit, then you can achieve what you want by either creating a wrapper around the `MyService` interface that injects the necessary data in the result model, or create a custom `CallAdapter` that parses the `Request` from the `Call` parameters it receives, and generates your desired result objects based on it (possible wrapping around the `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` implementation).

Comment: I'll probably use a Java Proxy around my interface

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you should have have `searchNext()` on the `result` but rather on the `service`.

Try something like below:

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService {
    RestClient.GitApiInterface service = RestClient.getClient();
    String query;
    Observable<GitResult> resultObservable;

    public Observable<GitResult> getUsersByName(String query) {
        this.query = query;
        resultObservable = service.getUsersByName(query, 0).cache();
        return resultObservable;
    }

    public Observable<GitResult> searchNext() {
        Observable nextResultObservable = resultObservable
                .flatMap(new Func1<GitResult, Observable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> call(GitResult gitResult) {
                        return service.getUsersByName(query, gitResult.getNextPage());
                    }
                });

        return nextResultObservable;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
final MyService service = new MyService();
// First load
service.getUsersByName("tom");
// consecutive calls
service.searchNext();
```

**Sample app** - https://gitlab.com/wizardkrishna/retrofit2-sample

**References**
[Consuming REST API using Retrofit2](https://github.com/ayon115/Retrofit2.0Sample)
[Observable Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29851258/206292)

Comment: Why do you think having the SearchResult.next() method is bad?

Comment: SearchResult is probably a model class, binding a service call to it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: I think having a service with state is even worst :)

Comment: `MyService` is just a wrapper around the actual service - `RestClient.GitApiInterface service`, you could call it something else :)

Comment: it's not the name. it's the role of that component. the fact that the result for that method depend on whatever you called another one before. it's so wrong.

Comment: I want to elaborate a little bit... Yes, having a `next()` on the model seems like a meh thing to do, but think of it like: `service.searchNext(previousResult)` for this to work i need to have inside the previous result the data i need to reconstruct the request. And my question was about carrying the request params into the result through retrofit. I can do it building a wrapper around the retrofit service (which is what i did) but it would be nice if there was a way to do it with retrofit.